# How did old international loans work?

Tags: international-trade

On June 11, 1782, John Adams secured a much needed loan for the new Republic from Holland. How exactly did this work in the days of strictly paper currency? What did it mean to loan internationally back then (and even today)?

Did Holland send their own currency? Did they send it in the form of some standard, i.e gold bullion? How did the U.S. pay this back? In some other standard? I just have no concept of how an international power could lend anything other than goods in the 18th century.

Comment: Good question. You might also want to try in the history stack exchange site

Comment: Indeed, this was an interesting question. @GuyLouzon, OP followed your advice and the scholars at History SE delivered: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/48617/how-did-old-international-loans-work.